# C++ Classes. Values inside class don't get updated

Tags: c++, class

for a class assignment I have to write a class definition. Its called Employee class, something really basic for my first c++ class.

My problem is in the first forloop, when I try to adjust the salary based on the new percentage. 
The variables inside the class don't change after that. I don't know what could be wrong anymore.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Employee
{
private:
    int emplSalary;
    string employeeName;

public:
    Employee();
    Employee(string name,int salary);
    string getName();
    int getSalary();
    void newSalary(int percent); 
    void input();
    void output();
};
Employee::Employee()
{
    emplSalary=0;
    employeeName="";
}
Employee::Employee(string name,int sal)
{
    employeeName=name;
    emplSalary =sal;
}
string Employee::getName()
{
    return employeeName;
}
int Employee::getSalary()
{
    return emplSalary;
}
void Employee::newSalary(int percent)
{

    emplSalary= emplSalary *(1+(percent/100));
    cout<<"I calculated"<<endl;
    /*
    if(percent < 0) 
    {
        cout<<"Invalid Percentage";
        cout<<"I calculated"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        emplSalary= emplSalary *(1+(percent/100));
        cout<<"I calculated"<<endl;
    }
    */
}
void Employee::input()
{
    cout << "Enter Name: "; 
        cin>> employeeName;
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"Enter Salary: " ;
        cin>>emplSalary;
        cout<<"\n";
}
void Employee::output()
{
    cout << "Name: " << employeeName <<" : "<< "Salary: " << emplSalary << endl;
    cout<<"\n";
}


int main()
{
    const int NUMBER_EMPLOYEE =1;
    Employee employees[NUMBER_EMPLOYEE];
    int percent;
    cout<<"Welcome to Employee program. Enter Name and Salary when prompted."<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n";


    for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_EMPLOYEE; i++)
    {

        employees[i]=Employee();
        employees[i].input();
        cout<<"What percentage to raise the salary: ";
        cin>>percent;
        employees[i].newSalary(percent);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_EMPLOYEE; i++)
    {
        employees[i].output();
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and the output is:

```
Welcome to Employee program. Enter Name and Salary when prompted.


Enter Name: 
Enter Salary: 
What percentage to raise the salary: I calculated
Name:  : Salary: 0
```

Comment: What is your actual input?

Comment: Once you run the program it asks for name and salary. To test I put in Marcus and 3000. then the percent to be calculated. 10.

Comment: emplSalary doesn't change after running this line:employees[i].newSalary(percent);  :: and it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
emplSalary= emplSalary *(1+(percent/100));
```

Because `percent` is an `int`, you are doing all integer math.

Suppose `percent` was 50.
The innermost part of your expression ends up being `50/100`, which is `0` in integer math.
(You intended for the result to be `0.50`).

To fix this, change the type of percent to be `double`.

Alternately, you can change 100 to be 100.0 (making it a `double`):

```
emplSalary= emplSalary *(1+(percent/100.0));
```

Comment: Thank you that indeed fixed the problem. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
emplSalary= emplSalary *(1+(percent/100));
```

This line, if your `percent` is less than 99, `percent/100` will be zero, that's why it has no affect to your result. You may want to use `double` type for your `emplSalary and percent`.

Answer (score 1):

```
emplSalary= emplSalary *(1+(percent/100));
```

You're performing integer arithmetic there (`emplSalaray` and `percent` are both of type `int`). This means that `percent / 100` will (unless percent is greater 99) always evaluate to 0. So the equation ends up being `emplSalary = emplSalary * 1`.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that when the original salary is zero (which is what happens when you write `employees[i]=Employee()` and the default constructor sets the salary to 0), raises of *any* percentage will always remain zero,

Second, note that dividing an `int` by another `int` will perform integer arithmetic, so the quotient gets truncated. Raises between 0 and 100 percent will therefore be rounded to 0%. Divide by 100.0 instead of 100 to resolve that problem.

Comment: Not to mention that `employees[i] = Employee();` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: O.o you are absolutely right. XD its rather redundant since I'm asking for input.

Comment: @zenrumi:  And the default constructor is already called when the array is created.